# AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute

Tags: python, kivy

I try to put texture into Image but get this error. It seems python not able to get this atribute from Image, but it should. Sorry for bad English

this is my kv.py file

```
import cv2
import kivy
import numpy as np
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.image import Texture
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import SliderTest

class Wrapper(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Wrapper, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cam1 = ObjectProperty(None)


class CamMain(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 33.0)
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        return Wrapper()

    def update(self, dt):
        _, frame = self.capture.read()
        texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        result = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
        texture.blit_buffer(result.tostring(), colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        App.get_running_app().root.cam1.texture = texture


if __name__ == "__main__":
    CamMain().run()
```

this is my CamMain.kv file

```
<Wrapper>:
    hue: hue
    saturation: saturation
    value:value
    cam1:cam1
    orientation: 'vertical'

    GridLayout:
        cols:2

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing:20
            padding:25
            Image:
                id:cam1
                size: self.texture_size
```

App.get_running_app().root.cam1.texture = texture
AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute 'texture'

Answer (score 0):

I just had to move cam1 = ObjectProperty(None) outside of **init**